# how to get stock total for all simple products linked to a configurable product in magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, stock, simple-product, qty

I want to get all the qty total for all simple products linked to a specific configurable product I have to do the following (check my code below) but it returns "0" on total, can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it for my case in list page it worked.

```
$totl_qty = 0;
            
            $configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
            $_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);
            foreach ($_children as $child){
                $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
               $totl_qty += $StockState->getStockQty($child->getId(), $child->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                
            }
     echo $totl_qty;
```